# Is it possible to change output device of audio element in mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I have a web app that outputs a voice using `<audio>` element of `html5` and I want to allow user to select listening to `audio` from earphone output or default audio output of mobile phone.

I tried `setSinkId` api but this api is not supported on some browsers and mobile browsers not support this api and I am struggling with this issue.

Any idea and recommendation would be really appreciated.

Comment: it is nothing a webdocument (HTML document)  can control. It is an user setting controlled by the user and the OS. It would be a security issue if a web document can override or change user settings.

Comment: @tacoshy so you say this is impossible to implement this feature? how meeting web platforms like google meet implement this feature on mobile devices? imagine you are loading google meet from your mobile browser and you want to toggle voice output between ear speaker and default speaker.

Comment: trusted plattform and the usage of browser build in controls. It is nothign the website controls but request to the browser and the browser will ask the suer for the explicit permission. But that is not playing an audiofile but using VoIP which is neither done HTML nor HTML Audio.

Comment: @tacoshy Actually I want to allow user to select audio output device of his/her mobile phone. I say that this API is not supported in all browser and I need a solution to implement this feature.

Comment: Read again... it is nothing you can control as it is an user setting and the cobtril ultimatively remains at the users control. There is a reason why not all browser support such API and rather stick to the direct OS selected audio device